# CASE WHEN Statement with two tables with table 2 column referencing has non-unique value

Tags: sql

I have a query that I have worked on and only one section has caused me fits. I am trying to create a column within the query based on the values of two tables. I have tried CASE WHEN and it functions, but due to the non-unique values involved, the row count in the query between the original query without increases. For example, this is the case when that I have written:

```
   Select  r.Id,
        r.RequiredOn AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time' 
               as RequiredDate,
        Concat(vs.Salutation, ' ',vs.FirstName, ' ', vs.LastName) as Name,
        oo.Name as RequestingOrganization,
        o.Name as Location,
        Case
            When r.IntendedOutcome = '1' Then 'T'
            When r.IntendedOutcome = '2' Then 'R'
        End as RequestType,
        etr.TypeRequested,
        Case
            When etr.Identifier is not null then etr.Identifier
            When etr.Identifier is null then ' '
        End as Identifier,
        f.OfferedOn,
        f.OfferResponse,
        r.DestinationCountryCodes,
        o.Id,
        CASE
            WHEN o.Id = oir.OrganizationId AND oir.OrganizationRoleId = 
                  'de51c814-f86d-49c9-941b-999a98be4894'
            THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
       END AS Bk1

        From [Request] r
            Left Join Recovered etr
            on etr.DistributionRequestId = r.Id      
        
            Left Join [Offer] f
                on f.Id = etr.Id
        
                Left Join [dbo].Contact vs
                    on vs.Id = r.SId

                        Left Join [dbo].Organization o
                            on o.Id = r.SLocationId or o.Id = r.RLocationId

                                Left Join [dbo].Organization oo
                                    on oo.Id = r.RequestingOrganizationId

                                    Left Join dbo.OrganizationInRole oir
                                        on oir.OrganizationId = o.Id

                       Where f.Response = 'Accepted' or f.Response is NULL
```

[image]

The picture shows that the OrganizationId is not unique with this table and therefore when an OrganizationId is matched and the OrganizationRoleId is found, it is bringing all of the OrganizationRoleId's over in the query and adding to it rather than just seeing that it has the particular Role ID and adding to the one row I need it to.

The Organization Role column in non-unique and every organization can multiple roles(sometimes 4-5). I need that if the OrganizationId is A and the matching OrganizationId in Table 2 has the identifier in the OrganizationRole column, then add a 1.

The Organization table (Table 2) has a OrganizationId column and a OrganizationRole column. The OrganizationId is non-unique as the OrgnanizationId could be used in 5 consecutive rows since that organization has 5 Roles.

The results that I am getting are that the query is pulling all of the Roles from Organizations that do match that table. It basically added 33% more rows to the query versus the original.

Comment: I can't fully understand the issue. Can you add a few rows of sample data and the expected result? Please only include the column that are relevant. A minimal example will do.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include sample data and the result you're attempting to obtain, as well as the complete SQL you're using (rather than just an out-of-context portion). See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: It sounds like you might need to pre-aggregate your data in some way with a sub-query or apply/lateral join. It's hard to follow what you mean so a set of sample data that illustrates your issue and the desired results will go a long way. And tag your specific database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say

> ... if the OrganizationId is A and the matching OrganizationId in Table 2 has the identifier in the OrganizationRole column, then add a 1.

Are you wanting to create a count of the number if times this condition is true? If so, you need to wrap your `CASE` in an aggregate function and group on the other rows.

Alternatively, as Stu suggests in the comments, you could pre-aggregate the `OrganizationInRole` table, filtering for the role you are actually interested in; something like

```
SELECT r.Id,
...
   oir.RoleCount AS Bk1

FROM [Request] r
    ...
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].Organization o 
        ON o.Id = r.SLocationId or o.Id = r.RLocationId
    ...
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT OrganizationId, COUNT(*) AS RoleCount
        FROM dbo.OrganizationInRole
        WHERE OrganizationRoleId = 'de51c814-f86d-49c9-941b-999a98be4894'
        GROUP BY OrganizationId) AS oir ON oir.OrganizationId = o.Id
 ...
```

You can do this for any other table which has multiple related rows, reducing them to a single row to join to and removing the need for aggregation and grouping in the main query.

Comment: Hi Tony,

I am not wanting a count persay, but if technically if the organization has the RoleId that matches that RoleIdentifier, then it would only be 1. Below is an explanation of what I am trying to achieve with psuedo code:

Comment: Check where 'Table 1'[OrganizationId]' = 'Table 2'[OrganizationId],
      IF WHERE 'Table 1'[OrganizationId] = 'Table 
           2'[OrganizationId] HAS A 'Table 2'[OrganizationRoleId] =   'de51c814-f86d-49c9-941b-999a98be4894', THEN 'TRUE'
    ELSE 'FALSE'

Comment: The problem is that there are other OrganizationRoleId's that are not 'de51c814-f86d-49c9-941b-999a98be4894', but the OrganizationId would still match. For rows in Table1 where there is a match for the OrganizationRoleId in Table2, it is also bringing over the other OrganizationRoleId's that don't match and adding rows to the query

Comment: Tony,
I tried the pre-aggregate that you and Stu suggested and no rows were added and it looks promising so far. I will comb through the data to confirm everything, but thanks. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Buckets - If you can provide the relationship between the tables, showing where there is a one-to-many or many-to-many link, and some sample data, it would help me to understand more of what you are trying to do. If you're not counting the number of instances of a particular role, and an Organisation can have many roles, you are going to get multiple rows in the results unless you do some aggregation. It would be good to know if you manage to sort it out :)